# Monaca/Cordova バーコードプラグイン使用時、読みとれるバーコードについて

Tags: monaca, cordova

アプリ開発初心者です。 
Monacaを利用して開発を進めております。 
Cordovaのバーコードプラグイン(plugins.barcodeScanner.scan)を用いて、バーコードをスキャンしているのですが、こちらですとJANコード等は読みとれるのですが、GS1コードが読み取れません。 
こちらのプラグインにて、GS1コードを読み取れるように設定できるものでしょうか。 
ご教示いただければ幸いです。 
よろしくお願い申し上げます。

CordovaのBarcodeScannerプラグインを組み込み、以下のように組んでおります。

以下script

```
function scanBarcode() {
　window.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(function(result) {
　　$('#gs1').val(result.text);
　}, function(error) {
　　alert("Scanning failed: " + error); 
　});
}
```

以下html

```
<ons-col width="100px">
　バーコード 
</ons-col>
<ons-col>
　<ons-button id="scan" modifier="cta" onClick ="scanBarcode()">スキャン</ons-button>
　<input type="hidden" id="gs1">
</ons-col>
```

Comment: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner#using-the-plugin

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/26621

Answer (score 0):

h2so5さんがリンクでCordovaのBarcodeScanerの使用方法について示されています。リンク先ではCordovaのBarcodeScanerで読み取り可能な(サポートしている)フォーマットについて、各端末毎に記載されています。

バーコードのフォーマットについては詳しくないため、GS1コードが読み取れるかどうかについてはわかりません。一応、AndroidやiOSではCODE_128(GS1-128)はサポートしているようです。
提示されているscriptでは、全ての**サポートしているフォーマット**がデフォルトで読み取り可能に設定されています。
（scanAPIのoptionを指定しない場合はデフォルト設定となる）
（但し、一部例外としてAndroidではPDF417/AZTECをデフォルトでサポートしないようです）

回答としては：

- 提示されているscriptで読み取れないのであれば質問内容で聞かれているGS1コードを読み取ることはできない（設定もできない）と考えられます。

Answer (score 0):

GS1バーコードは元の名前がRSS(Reduced Space Symbology)です。
基本は14桁でJAN/EAN/UPCバーコードと上位互換で移行が容易になるように設計されたもので、
RSS14とも呼ばれていました。

同じ14桁ですが、もっとサイズを小さく印刷できるものを RSS Limited、
14桁だけではなく、付加情報もあるものを RSS Expanded、
複数のバーコードを積み上げてまとめたものを Stacked と呼んだり、色々あります。

h2so5さん紹介のページで、RSS14, RSS_EXPANDEDと記述されているのがGS1に該当します。
しかしサポートしているOSが限定的で、見る限りではRSS14はAndroid,Windows8,WindowsPhone8のみ、RSS_EXPANDEDはAndroidのみサポートのようです。
使用しているOSがそれらでなければ読み取れないでしょう。

また、小さく印刷出来ることを売りにしているバーコードなので、使っているカメラの解像度
などの性能や、撮影条件が悪いと、サポートしていても認識率は良くないと思われます。